# Travelling after living in Australia before returning to the US?

Tags: visas, passports, australia, us-citizens

My daughter is an American citizen living in Australia for a year.  When her one year visa is up does she have to return to the US or can she travel to other countries with her valid US passport before returning home?

Comment: What makes you think she wouldn't be able to ?

Comment: When she left from DFW airport the customs people there told her she had to return within 1 year.

Comment: That's odd, they didn't specify why ?

Comment: They told her that her type of visa was only good for a year, but that has nothing to do with her passport and other international travel?

Comment: Ah perhaps what they meant is she has to leave Australia within 1 year, that has nothing with other travel plans and her passport. Mark's answer is correct :)

Comment: I'm confused as to why she's be speaking to customs on the way out via DFW. The USA doesn't have exit immigration or customs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She may have to leave Australia, depending on the type of visa she's on, but there's no reason she has to return to the US immediately.  As long as she has a valid passport with >6 months free on it, and valid visas and flights for the countries she wishes to visit (and sometimes evidence of an eventual ticket back to the US), she can travel indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks, that's the most help I have gotten yet...even with a call to the State Department.

Comment: Bizarre, it's a fairly common travel problem for people living in a country for a while. I've lived in several now and often travel post-stint.  Hope she enjoys it!

Comment: She is loving it!  Thank you for the help!  She needs to get international data though so I'm not the one doing this!